# Question on relation between a parabolic sobolev space and a sobolev bochner space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

For parabolic sobolev spaces I follow the following definition:

[image]

According to this definition, we have that $W^{1,1,2}(I \times \Omega)=L^2(I; W^{1,2}(\Omega)) \cap W^{1,2}(I; W^{-1,2}(\Omega))$

> ***Now my question is***: If we have a function such that $f \in W^{1,2}(I; L^2(\Omega))$ with, in addition, $ \nabla f(x,\cdot) \in
>  L^2(I;L^2(\Omega))$, can we claim that $f \in W^{1,1,2}(I \times
>  \Omega)$?

Instinctively I would say yes, but I need a math confirmation.

Any hint or help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. You have $$f \in W^{1,2}(I;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(I;W^{1,2}(\Omega))$$ and you are asking whether this function is in
$$W^{1,1,2}(I \times \Omega)=L^2(I;W^{1,2}(\Omega))\cap W^{1,2}(I;W^{-1,2}(\Omega)).$$

This follows from the fact $L^2 \hookrightarrow W^{-1,2}$ where we identified $L^2$ with its dual as usual in the corresponding Gelfand triple. See also [that question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273371/a-question-about-gelfand-triples). Then it is easy to check that $W^{1,2}(I;L^2(\Omega))$ is continuously embedded in $W^{1,2}(I;W^{-1,2}(\Omega))$, just use the norm definition.

Comment: Probably it remains to justify that $f\in L^2(I;W^{1,2}(\Omega))$. This is nearly obvious, since $f\in L^2(I;L^2(\Omega))$ and $\nabla f \in L^2(I;L^2(\Omega))$, but I think in the OP some technical details on this point are also needed (in particular, about the measurability [as in the definition of Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)). For instance one could mollify $f$ with respect to $\Omega$-valued variable and show that such approximations converge in $L^2(I;W^{1,2}(\Omega))$, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @Skeeve Thank you for your comment. Yes, that could also be. kaithkolesidou can you please clarify whether my answer solved your question, or are you asking about a different aspect e.g. the measurability as pointed out by Skeeve.